# How to map seperately dynamic number of query parameters and pageable information in rest call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am having a rest call where the front end sends me page and size and also a dynamic number of query parameters in the url. I map them all using this piece of code:

From postman:

```
http://localhost:8080/something/search?page=0&size=10&sort=applicationId,asc&applicationId=name1&applicationId=name2&reference=12345
```

The way I map them:

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<ObjectToReturn>> getObjectWithDynamicCriteria(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params)
```

My problem with this approach is that both pageable and multivalue map contains the same information about the pageable object.

```
  Page request [number: 0, size 10, sort: applicationId: ASC]
  params {page=[0], size=[10], sort=[applicationId,asc], applicationId=[name1, name2], reference=[12345]}
```

I process the multivalue map values for example the application id and the reference but before I remove the page and size from the map because they already exist in the pageable object.

Is there any way to have lets say pageable object and multivalue map but the multivalue map to not have the -->  page=[0], size=[10], sort=[applicationId,asc]?

Comment: No there isn't. An `@RequestParam` annotated `Map` will automatically have all the request parameters. So unless you define your own object, annotation and `MethodArgumentHandler` this isn't possible.

Comment: Can I combine the MethodArgumentHandler  with the dynamic number of parameters?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, however simply filtering the known attributes from the map is a lot easier.